# Is there a practical difference between different ways of food becoming obligated in ma'aser?

Tags: maaser-tithes, mishneh-torah, masechet-maasrot

The Rambam ([Ma'aser 3:3](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Tithes.3.3)), apparently based on the Yerushalmi ([Ma'asrot 4:1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Jerusalem_Talmud_Ma'asrot.18b?lang=he)), lists six things that make food fixed (קבע) in the obligation for ma'aser: bringing it into a courtyard, buying/selling, fire, salt, separating teruma, and Shabbat (the Ra'avad says he should have also added pickling). Later ([4:2](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Tithes.4.2)) he clarifies that all these things, except for bringing into the house, are forbidden from the rabbis.

These thing are all mentioned throughout the Mishna in Ma'asrot ([3:5](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Maasrot.3.5), [4:1-3](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Maasrot.4.1)) as making food obligated in ma'aser. However, as presented by the Mishna, there is another thing mentioned throughout ([2:5](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Maasrot.2.5), [3:3](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Maasrot.3.3) [3:8-10](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Maasrot.3.8), [4:5](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Maasrot.4.5)) that makes food obligated, namely, taking a lot at once. For example, taking more than one fig or grain of barley at a time means that it becomes obligated in ma'aser and it can no longer be eaten informally (עראי). The Rambam also mentions this as the definition of informal eating ([3:19](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Tithes.3.19), quoting [4:5](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Maasrot.4.5)), but not as part of the list of six things.

Is there any legal difference between the six things that make produce fixed for ma'aser, and taking many pieces of food at a time? I don't see any such distinction made by the Mishna. But in the Rambam's scheme, it seems from a superficial reading as if he makes a distinction.

For example, the Rambam says you can make someone else's produce obligated in ma'aser by doing one of the six things, but he doesn't make this explicit about taking a lot of food together at once ([Ma'aser 3:7](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Tithes.3.7)). So in this case, a literal reading would be that if you take two of your friend's figs, your friend can still eat them separately without taking ma'aser. This could be reasonable, because (as the Rambam presents it) you're allowed to eat the food informally before one of the six things happen to the food, so it might depend more on the person eating it than on what happens to the food itself. However, the Mishna itself uses for all of these cases the same wording of חייב (which, however, does have two possible meanings: "he is obligated," or "it is obligated").

So does the Rambam really mean to distinguish between taking a lot of food together, and other actions that make food fixed for ma'aser? If so, what's the Rambam's source for this distinction?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/84783/759 Those six things don't make it obligated in Maaser. Something being obligated in Maaser, something being fixed for Maaser, and something being a non-temporary manner of consumption are three different categories which you don't seem to be clearly distinguishing.

Comment: @DoubleAA I used the language the Mishna uses when quoting the Mishna, and the language the Rambam uses when quoting the Rambam. The Mishna says חייב about all of them. The case here is your second and third categories which the Mishna doesn't seem to distinguish but the Rambam does

Comment: @ba If you're deliberately using original language [to the point of obfuscation] I think  you should put the relevant ambiguous terminology in quotes to indicate the exact sourcing and that the words shouldn't necessarily be taken in their ordinary senses.

Comment: @DoubleAA "Obligation" is a general concept that can apply both גמר and קבע, and the entire question is about קבע so there is no obfuscation between those two.   It's only obfuscation between becoming fixed and eating in a non-temporary manner if you presuppose the Rambam's categories, but the question is *about* the Rambam's categories

Comment: I haven't presupposed anyone's categories. Just encouraged you to write clearer. If you don't want to have assigned categories, be clear in your writing that you aren't

Comment: I am not in the suggia and my memory is not good, but see the first Tosfot in Betsa 10b, 
3. הכניס שבולים לעשות מהם עיסה אוכל מהן עראי ופטור אבל אם לאכול קבע חייב מדרבנן 
4. כיון דשרו למיכל מינייהו עראי בלא מעשר איכא היכירא דמידי דמיחייב מדאורייתא אסור לאכול אפי' עראי אחר מירוח 
5. כדתנן בפ"ק דמסכת פיאה (מ"ו) מאכילין לחיות ולעופות עד שימרח 
6. אבל בתר מירוח לא וכל אכילת בהמה חשיב אכילת עראי        Seems to hold your opinion in our machloket Need time and strength to study back

Answer (score 3):

Here is an element of answer. My understanding is based on Gemara BM 88a-89b, Betsa 13 and 34-35.

The owner, when he finished the work, the harvesting is ready,  takes it at home and then he cannot eat without Maaser. But there is an opinion in Gemara, saying that for fruits that need goren before consumption, e.g. wheat, grape that need to become wine, the duty is before the home, it's beginning from the harvesting. For fruits immediately consumable, as grape that needs to be eaten as fruits, the duty begins at home. The Raavad maasrot 4.1 rules as this last opinion.

There is a rabbinic duty, regarding a situation in which the owner doesn't want to take the fruits at home, and someone buy an amount of fruits.In this situation, since the work is finished, and something replaces the home taking, there is a rabbinic duty. This is the opinion of Tosfot 88a, but Rashi explains that for the buyer duty, we don't need the true end of the work, but the Gemara at the begining of the suggia was thinking that there are min Hatora two ends of work, one for the owner and one for the buyer. But in conclusion there is only the goren of the owner who take his fruits at home. There is no fundamental difference between Rashi and Tosfot regarding the explanation of the duty of the buyer.

The end of the work is for the owner who takes fruits at home, is when he brings together all the fruits, or, more accurately, when he begins to make this. If he decides to take the fruits in the market to sell them, he is patur from maaser by the Tora rule, but rabbinically he is chayav. There is  a kind of mini harvesting, rabbinically speaking, when he sells a part of the fruits and want to take at home, afterwards, the major part of the harvesting., To buy a minimum of 2 fruits as Gemara and Tosfot BM 88 d.h Baal Habayit said.

To make a real meal can rabbinically replace the home meal. If the work is finished and the owner eats two fruits, or eats a cooked meal, there is a rabbinic duty.

Several things can make the eating a serious meal. If the fruits became prepared by cooking, or salting, or the timing, if the time is a time of great meal, as Shabbat.

For salting (ספיתה) without any duty because of selling, we need also two fruits for gmar melacha. Whe need two fruits to have an opposition against the greet goren, and then, there is Gmar Melacha, and it is called a "kviut" before eating with salt. This regards the owner. When there is a selling, we have a gmar Melacha and the selling is a rabbinic equivalent of entering at home. If we have two fruits, without selling and without salting, there is no prohibition to eat, even many fruits, it is still an achilat arayi despite the quantity (BM 89b).

Mishnayot

2.5

> ב,ה  האומר לחברו הא לך איסר זה, ותן לי בו חמש תאנים--לא יאכל עד שיעשר, דברי רבי מאיר.  רבי יהודה אומר, אוכל אחת אחת, ופטור; ואם צירף, חייב.  אמר רבי יהודה, מעשה בגינת ורדים שהייתה בירושלים, והיו תאניה נמכרות משלוש ומארבע באיסר; ולא הופרש ממנה תרומה ומעשר מעולם

Mishna 2.6

> ב,ו  האומר לחברו הא לך איסר זה בעשרים תאנים שאבור לי, בורר ואוכל.  באשכול שאבור לי, מגרגר ואוכל.  ברימון שאבור לי, פורט ואוכל.  באבטיח שאבור לי, סופת ואוכל.  אבל אם אמר בעשרים תאנים אלו, בשני אשכולות אלו, בשני רימונים אלו, בשני אבטיחים אלו--אוכל כדרכו ופטור, מפני שקנה במחובר לקרקע

Yachin

> פורט
>   עיי' פ"א נ"ד. דמדאין המקח נגמר עד אחר שתלשו מקח בתלוש קובע למעשר ואף לאכלו עראי והרי כשתלש איזה מהן נגמ"ל מדאין לו גמ"ל אחרת. אבל לגרגר ולפרוט מותר דבכה"ג לא נגמ"ל גם לקונה והרי כל ז' הדברים [פ"א נ"ג] אין קובעים רק בנגמ"ל [ועי' רפ"ג]:

Buyng makes a chyuv maaser only if the kinyan is on fruits already separated from the tree, and is after harvesting. When it is the case, informal eating is prohibited before maaser taking. The Mishna is talking about fruits in the garden or the field. The buying replaces the home taking after harvesting. See below Mishna 5.1

Mishne Tora

> ה,ב  הלוקח במחובר לקרקע, או שלקח תלוש לשלח לחברו--לא נקבעו, ויש לו לאכול מהן עראי.  [ג] האומר לחברו הא לך איסר זה, ותן לי בו חמש תאנים--הרי זה אוכל אחת אחת, ופטור; ואם צירף, חייב לעשר.

Mishna 3.2

> ג,ב  המוציא את פועליו בשדה--בזמן שאין להם עליו מזונות, אוכלין ופטורין; אבל אם יש להם עליו מזונות, אוכלין אחת אחת מן התאנה, אבל לא מן הסל ולא מן הקופה ולא מן המוקצה.

Mishna 3.3

> ג,ג  השוכר את הפועל לעשות עימו בזיתים--אמר לו על מנת לאכול בזיתים, אוכל אחת אחת ופטור; ואם צירף, חייב.  לנכש בבצלים--אמר לו על מנת לאכול ירק, מקרטם עלה עלה ואוכל; ואם צירף, חייב.

Halachot of the worker are conitioned by a special status, he can eat how many as he wants when he is working at the time of harvesting. But in other times, the Tora doesn't give him this status. So he eats as if he buyed the fruits, and has a din of buyer, and if he accumulates fruits, we have harvesting and buying, he cannot eat, even informally. When he makes with the owner some conditions of eating, regarding quantity, Rashi and Rambam hold that he has a rabbinical status of buyer and cannot accumulate. Rabenu Tam disagrees.

Mishne Tora

> ה,יב  [י] שכרו **לנכש** עימו בזיתים, והתנה הפועל שיאכל בזיתים--הרי זה אוכל מן האילן אחת אחת, ופטור; ואם צירף, חייב.  [יא] שכרו לנכש בבצלים, והתנה לאכול ירק--מקרסם עלה עלה, ואוכל; ואם צירף, חייב.
>
> [יא] שכרו לנכש בבצלים, והתנה לאכול ירק--מקרסם עלה עלה, ואוכל; ואם צירף, חייב.
>
> ה,יג  קצץ הפועל שיאכל ליטרה של זיתים, אוכל אחת אחת; ואם צירף, חייב לעשר   **הואיל והוא אוכל דבר קצוב, הרי זה כלוקח שאם צירף נקבע**.
>
> ה,יד  לא קצץ, אלא היה אוכל בדין תורה--מצרף ואוכל כל מה שירצה:  והוא, שלא יספות במלח.  אבל אם ספת במלח אחת אחת, מותר; שתיים שתיים--אסור, שהרי נקבעו במלח.

Mishna 3.8

> ג,ח  תאנה שהיא עומדת בחצר--אוכל אחת אחת, ופטור; ואם צירף, חייב.  רבי שמעון אומר, אחת בימינו ואחת בשמאלו ואחת בפיו.  עלה לראשה--ממלא את חיקו, ואוכל.

Melechet Shelomo

> אוכל אחת אחת. אבל שתים לא דהוי גרן וראיית פני חצר בבת אחת ובהא מודה ר' טרפון

Two fruits from a Fig tree that is in the courtyard, we have harvesting and courtyard, generating together a chyuv, the fruits need terumot and maasrot.  We are speaking even about the owner.

Mishne Tora

> ,יד  [טו] תאנה שהיא עומדת בחצר--אוכל ממנה אחת אחת, ופטור; **ואם צירף**, חייב במעשר.  במה דברים אמורים, בשהיה עומד בקרקע.  אבל אם עלה לראש התאנה--ממלא את חיקו ואוכל שם, שאין אוויר החצר קובע למעשר

Mishna 3.9

> ג,ט  גפן שהיא נטועה בחצר, נוטל את כל האשכול; וכן ברימון, וכן באבטיח, דברי רבי טרפון.  רבי עקיבה אומר, מגרגר באשכול, ופורט ברימון, וסופת באבטיח.  כוסבר שהיא זרועה בחצר--מקרטם עלה עלה, ואוכל; **ואם צירף,** חייב.  הסיאה והאיזוב והקורנית שבחצר--אם היו נשמרין, חייבין

The Mishna treats the case of the owner in his courtyard. The  permitted  informal eating is only when there is no harvesting. This case is  similar to the case in Mishna 2.6 (Rash, Melechet Shelomo, TYT). There, the buyer is a rabbinic equivalent of the owner in his courtyard. Therefore we only miss harvesting to prohibit informal eating. This is true for Rabbi Akiva only. For Rabbi Tarfon, the Yerushalmi gives a pair of interpretations.

Mishne Tora

> ד,יז  [יח] כוסבר שהיא זרועה בחצר, מקרסם עלה עלה ואוכל; ואם צירף, חייב לעשר.  וכן כל כיוצא בזה.

Mishna 3.10

> ג,י  תאנה שהיא עומדת בחצר, ונוטה לגינה--אוכל כדרכו, ופטור.  עומדת בגינה, ונוטה לחצר--אוכל אחת אחת, ופטור; ואם צירף, חייב.  עומדת בארץ ונוטה לחוצה לארץ, או עומדת בחוצה לארץ ונוטה לארץ--הכול הולך אחר העיקר; ובבתי ערי חומה, הכול הולך אחר העיקר.  ובערי מקלט, הכול הולך אחר הנוף; ובירושלים, הכול הולך אחר הנוף.

The owner, when he wants to take all the harvesting at home, and he still didn't leave the garden, can accumulate a quantity of fruits and eat them. Because there is no gemar melacha, regarding the owner who looks for a broader quantity of fruits, there is no problem to eat a great quantity. See the drasha in Gemara BM 87b.
כנפשך כנפש של בעל הבית כך נפשו של פועל מה נפשך אוכל ופטור אף נפשו של פועל אוכל ופטור

The owner and the worker who can eat from the Tora eat normally without problem of maasrot. For the buyer there is an asmachta teaching that rabbinically he cannot.

Mishna 4.3

> ד,ג  הנוטל זיתים מן המעטן--טובל אחד אחד במלח, ואוכל; ואם מלח ונתן לפניו, חייב.  רבי אליעזר אומר, מן המעטן הטהור, חייב; ומן הטמא, פטור, מפני שהוא מחזיר את המותר

For salt you need to accumulate two salted olives, the Rash quotes the Yerushalmi that we need both, to accumulate 2 fruits, that is harvesting and salting.

Rambam

> המולח פירות בשדה נקבעו. טבל הזיתים אחד אחד במלח ואכל פטור. הפוצע זיתים כדי שיצא השרף מהם פטור. הנוטל זיתים מן המעטן טובל אחד אחד במלח ואוכל ואם מלח ונתן לפניו חייב וכן כל כיוצא בזה

Mishna 4.5

> ד,ה  המקלף בשעורים--מקלף אחת אחת, ואוכל; ואם קילף ונתן לתוך ידו, חייב.  המולל מלילות של חיטים--מנפה מיד ליד, ואוכל; ואם נפה לתוך חיקו, חייב.  כוסבר שזרעה לזרע, ירקה פטור; זרעה לירק, מתעשרת זרע וירק.  רבי אליעזר אומר, השבת מתעשרת זרע וירק וזירין; וחכמים אומרים, אין מתעשר זרע וירק אלא השחלים והגרגיר בלבד

This Mishna shows, following the previous Mishnayot of the same chapter, that in some situations, to eat without cooking or salting, but in great quantity, is an achilat keva.

Moreover, the Rambam 3.19 seems to accredite this lecture.

Rambam 3.19

> כיצד אכילת עראי:  כגון שהיה מקלף שעורים ואוכל, מקלף אחת אחת; ואם קילף וכנס לתוך ידו, חייב לעשר.  היה מולל מלילות של חיטים, מנפה מיד ליד ואוכל; ואם ניפה בתוך חיקו, חייב.  ואין צריך לומר, אם ניפה בכלי--שאין זה עראי

The last words, שאין זה עראי seem to explain that the way of eating indicates if you need to make maaser.

The comment called Mishna Rishona in Mishna 4.4 is very astonished about this Rambam because the Gemara Betsa 13b analyzes our Mishna following the rules of digun (goren) and says that generally in halachot, formal eating needs a great amount of fruits, not only two or three seeds , but more than kabetsa, following the Mishna in succa chapter 2 regarding eating informally out of the succa.

But after reflection on the comment of Tosfot Betsa 13b, analyzed in Tosfot Yom Tov on our Mishna, itself explained by the Shoshanim Ledavid, I understand that there Mishna treats a case in which the eater is for instance in the courtyard, and the accumulation of grain in his hand is a kind of goren (but the Chazon Ish Maasrot siman 4 [paragraph 16](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14335&st=&pgnum=326) says that it is in the field, but since he doesn't want to take this amount of fruits at home, there is already a prohibition of informal eating). So, there is no notion of achilat keva by the way of the quantity of eating. (See below a quotation of Tosfot Yom Tov and Shoshanim Ledavid with  a bit of explanation I added in square brackets)

Mishna 5.1

> לקח במחובר לקרקע, פטור; לקח לשלוח לחברו, פטור

The buyer has this stringency only if he bought the fruits after their separation from the tree.

So, now we understand the Rambam 3.3

> אבל אם הייתה כוונתו להוליכן לבית--הרי זה מותר לאכול מהן עראי אחר שנגמרה מלאכתן, עד שייקבעו למעשר.  [ג] ואחד משישה דברים קובע למעשרות, ואלו הן--הבית, והמקח, והאש, והמלח, והתרומה, והשבת; וכולן, אין קובעין אלא בדבר שנגמרה מלאכתו.

*Discussion:*

The duty occurs after gmar melacha, which can be accumulation of two fruits, followed by house, selling, fire, salt, teruma, Shabbat. The concept of two fruits is not one of the six, it is the prerequisite. The 5 items of the lists out of home are rabbinic equivalents of home. They say, the fruits are ready without coming to home.

And as says the Rambam in the first statement, this is part of Halacha 3.2 in standard editions, if there is a gmar melacha without one of the six steps enumerated, the owner can eat as many as he wants together.  Formal eating is a formal decision that the fruits will not go home, they definitely don't go home. If the eating is not formal enough, we still see them as if they wait to go home (מחזיר את המותר see Betsa 34b). So, the Rambam is not contradictory, the list of 6 causes of duty is exhaustive and the kushia of the Mishna Rishona is solved because the formality of the eating regards the question if there is a goren that will not go home, not the quantity of eating. After the occurrence of Achilat keve, you cannot eat even one fruit because this is Achilat Keva, as eating one fruit at home.

The Chazon Ish zerayim, hilchot Maasrot, siman 4, [paragraph 11](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14335&st=&pgnum=325) explains that the Mishna 4.5 is in the field and that there is a concept of formal eating, he called "מכאן אני אוכל"  (paraphrasing the last mishna in the fourth chapter of Betsa, and the fruits are still not destined to go home) independent from gemar melacha (the main harvesting). He discusses the case of salting without Gmar Melacha. Indeed, the Gemara Betsa 35a counts only Teruma, Shabbat, Chatser and Mekach for duties that needs the prerequisite Gmar Melacha. Salting and Cooking are not included. But it's clear that according to most rishonim (following how they understand Rashi Betsa 13b) there is such a notion of formal eating without gmar Melacha. See also Betsa 35 and Rashi there. But practically, there is no case in which you cannot see the formal eating without an equivalent of goren, moreover, a goren that entails chyuv without home because the eating will be out of the house. Rambam needs Gmar Melacha for salt, apparently against the Chazon Ish understanding of the Bavli. Therefore, I want to assume that Rambam needs always Gmar melacha, even for formal eating. And he is close to the explanation of TYT in Rashi quoted below (following my pshat in TYT).

**So, in conclusion**, the Yerushalmi, quoted in Rambam 3.3, doesn't need to include formal eating in the enumeration, because it is an equivalent of selling or salting for fruits they are not ready to eat without salt. This is perhaps the meaning of Chazon Ish [11.17](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14335&st=&pgnum=327).

---

Tosfot Yom Tov and Shoshanim Ledavid

> Tosfot Yom Tov.
>   ואם קילף ונתן לתוך ידו חייב. משמע אפילו אחת אחת. [פירוש לפירושו, נתן את השעורים אחת אחת לתוך ידו. ] דאי תימא דווקא בצירף ונתן לתוך ידו קשיא רישא [פירוש, אם כשהמשנה אומרת מקלף אחת אחת ואוכל מיירי בצירף למה מותר לו לאכול?] וכן נראה לי שהוא דעת רש"י שפירש בפרק קמא דביצה דף יג עמוד ב' וזה לשונו חייב במעשר דהוה ליה קבע עד כאן [פירוש, לא היה חיוב מעשרות מטעם גורן אלא מטעם קביעות לאכילה]. אלא שהתוספות כתבו עליו דלא נהירא דבסמוך משמע שהטעם מפני שהוא גמר מלאכה הואיל והוא קולף הרבה ביחד דהיינו דגונו עד כאן לשונם. והכי אמרינן התם למעשר אין, לשבת לא מי איכא מידי דלענין שבת לא הוי גמר מלאכה ולמעשר הוי גמר מלאכה. ונראה לי דרש"י מפרש קבע ורצה לומר ובכך הוי גרנו [פירוש לא כמו שמשמע מפשטות לשונו של רש"י, וגם לא כמו שתוספות הבין את רש"י, אלא רש"י התכוון דהוה גרנו לתוך ידו]. וכן נראה מלשונו בדבור המתחיל והרי גרנו וכו'. ולפי זה קושייתנו על התוספות. [פירוש לפירושו אם מדובר בשצירף לפני שהכניס לתוך ידו, אז גם בלי שיכניס לתוך ידו צריך להיות אסור לאכול, ואגב יש להעיר וצריכים לומר שיש כאן ראיית פני הבית כי מדובר בבעל הבית ודיגון לבד לא מחייב, אם הוא מתכוון לשמור את הפירות לעצמו, או שהוא מוליכם לשוק ואז דיגון מחייב כבר בשדה] ונראה לי דתנא אורחא דמילתא נקט וכשמצטרף נותנם לתוך ידו והרבה דנקטי התוספות לאו דווקא דבשתים חייב [ורש"י ותוספות אמרו דבר אחד] והרמב"ם פרק ג' דהלכות מעשר העתיק המשנה כלשונה.‏
>
> In summary, the Tosfot Yom Tov says that Rashi and Tosfot understand that the Mishna deals with a duty because of the end of the work. And end of work works to entail a duty because the fruits are not taken at home.

Shoshanim Ledavid [page 132](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22630&st=&pgnum=132&hilite=)

He explains the Tosfot Yom Tov.

> ואם וכו' דאי תימא וכו' שלכאורה משמע ממאי דקתני ואם קלף ונתן לתוך ידו דרצה לומר אם קלף הרבה שעורים ביחד שהוא דרך דיגון וגם נתן בידו כולם כאחד דהוה דרך קבע אז הוא דחייב [כלומר שהחיוב בא כתוצאה משני שלבים, הראשון הצטברות הרבה פירות במקום מסויים, והשני הצטברות הפירות בתוך היד] ועל זה בא רבינו התוספות יום טוב להוכיח שאינו כן דאם כן קשיא רישא דמדקתני קולף אחד אחד ואוכל מיד מוכח דתרתי בעינן לפטורא שיקלוף אחד אחד שלא כדרך דיגון וגם כן שיאכל כל אחד מיד שקלפו קודם שיקלוף השני כדי שלא יהא אכילת קבע הרי דבחדא לחיובא סגי [פירוש ויוצא מזה שכדי לחייב מספיק או דיגון או אכילה של כמה גרעיני שעורים ביחד] ואם כן סיפא דקתני ואם קלף ונתן לתוך ידו דהיינו הרבה דרך קבע בהא סגי לחיובא [כי עכשיו בדיוקא דסיפא משמע שצריך שני שלבים כדי להיות חייב] ובעל כרחך מאי דתנן ואם קלף רצה לומר אפילו קלף אחד אחד שלא כדרך דיגון אפילו הכי חייב מטעם קביעותא והוכיח התוספות יום טוב שכן דעת רש"י דביצה מדקא יהיב טעמא דהוי ליה קבע שמע מינה שזהו עיקר המחייבו לפי שנותן הרבה לתוך ידו דהוי ליה קבע ולעולם אפילו לא קלפם בצירוף אלא אחד אחד [חיוב משום אכילת קבע לא תלוי בגמר מלאכה]. ועל זה כתב אלא שהתוספות הוכיחו שטעם החיוב דסיפא לפי שקולף הרבה ביחד דהיינו דרך דיגון ואם כן לדידהו הדרא קושיא לדוכתא דמסיפא משמע דבעינן תרתי לחיובא דהיינו דרך דיגון ואכילת קבע דהיינו נותן לתוך ידו [כי נותן לתוך ידו הוא לשון של אכילת קבע ולא לשון של דיגון] ומרישא משמע איפכא דבעינן תרתי לפטורא ואי בצר ליה חדא חייב ואהא תירץ דאין הכי נמי דבחדא סגי לחיובא [הסבר, כאן דיגון מחייב, שמע מינה, או שמדובר בלוקח, או שמדובר בבעל הבית שמתכוון להוליכם לשוק, או שמדובר בבעל הבית שנמצא בחצר] והכא קתני ונתן לתוך ידו אורחא דמילתא קתני אבל לא שיהיה זה טעם החיוב דבלא זה חייב  מכי קלף הרבה ביחד [אחרי שצבר אותם הוא חייב גם אם אוכל אחת אחת, בלי לתת לתוך ידו]  דבהכי מיירי מתניתין לדידהו ולענין דינא אין חילוק בין רש"י לתוספות כלל זוהי כוונת התוספות יום טוב
>
> In summary, the SLD understands that the Tosfot Yom Tov says that there is no Machloket between Rashi and Tosfot. He holds that both agree that either formal eating without digun, or digun without formal eating entails the duty. I personally am not convinced by this pshat in TYT. My understanding explained above is closest to the understanding of the Bet David [page 66](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22456&st=&pgnum=66&hilite=).
>   See also Chazon Ish maasrot siman 4, [paragraph 17](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14335&st=&pgnum=327) for the explanation of Rashi.

This answer needs to be reworked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96098/discussion-between-b-a-and-kouty).